# How to add file in Ms Sharepoint 2010 Workspace programmatically?

Tags: c#-4.0, sharepoint

Is it possible to use C# and add files in the offline folder of MS Sharepoint 2010 Workspace?

The C# console application would not need to check for a connection and possibly wait for one restart or whatever, as Ms Sharepoint Workspace automatically snycs once a connection is established.

I couldn'T find any clues using google or the MS Sharpoint Workspace SDK.